# Getting Flot Chart to work with bar graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm having trouble getting the bars to show any data.  The data works fine in the pie charts but no data is displayed in the bar charts.  I can't figure out why but hoping one of you can.
Here is the data i'm working with.

DATA

```
Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
  color: "#0150AC"
  data: "8.00"
  label: "Please rate the location of our property."
  ticks: "Please rate the location of our property."
  __proto__: Object
1: Object
  color: "#DE6E26"
  data: "8.00"
  label: "Please rate the friendliness and courtesy of our staff."
  ticks: "Please rate the friendliness and courtesy of our staff."
  __proto__: Object
2: Object
  color: "#559B1E"
  data: "1.60"
  label: "Please rate the cleanliness of your room upon check-in."
  ticks: "Please rate the cleanliness of your room upon check-in."
 __proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

OPTIONS

```
bars: Object
  show: true
__proto__: Object
_proto__: Object
```

PLACEHOLDER

```
selector: "#prime_bar_chart"
```

CALL METHOD

```
function buildGraph(placeholder, data, options) {
    $.plot(placeholder, data, {

    series: options,

    legend: {
        show: true,
        backgroundColor:'#E1DFE0',
        margin:[-55, 0]
}});
```

}

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with some sample data? btw, should you not have a array of arrays in the object.data?

Comment: Documentation says object or arrays.  And it works with objects in the pie chart.  It's going to take me as second to put together the sample data I have to jump into quick meeting.

Comment: Just checked __[my version](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/Mootools-chart-flot)__ of Flot and indeed the bar plugin expects a array of arrays `[[x, y],[x, y], etc ]`. If you check my link and see the bars/pie examples it will be more clear.

Comment: @Sergio Yeah I was missing the multiple arrays.  Works like a champ now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Sergio is correct.  Line and bar charts require data in the following format

```
[ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]
```

Pie charts are a little different and can except a single data value.

Here's a fiddle [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/qLZpr/) with your data.

BTW, `ticks` is not a property of the series object but rather the `xaxis, yaxis`, see [here](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes).

Comment: Thanks.  I have mine set up like that now but it's not liking the data for some reason. I'll figure it out but at least I have some bars showing to work with.

Comment: @TimLieberman, in your above example your data value is a string, make sure you are casting it to a numeric type.

Comment: I tested either both ways and it worked as a string.  I am though casting it as number now.

Comment: I also figured out the bad data.  I wasn't making it a multiple array.